# How To Update Existing Data from DB with a Foreign Key in Laravel 7

Tags: database, laravel, crud

I have existing data from my SQL database which I want to update for renewal on the membership in the laravel project I'm creating. I want a foreign key `user_id` which links my `users` table to my `money_trades` table.

Schema in `money_trades` table

```
Schema::create('money_trades', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('mt_number');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

        $table->string('bank');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('mt_first_name');
        $table->string('mt_last_name');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('mt_account');
        $table->integer('mt_deposit');
        $table->integer('mt_renewFee');
        $table->string('mt_leverage');
        $table->string('expiry_date');

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

MoneyTradeController.php `store`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $request->validate([
        'bank' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
        'mt_first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'mt_last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'mt_account' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'mt_deposit' => ['required', 'integer', 'max:1000000', 'min:500'],
        'mt_renewFee' => ['required', 'integer', 'max:1000000'],
        'mt_leverage' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'expiry_date' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],


    ]);

    $moneyTrade = new MoneyTrade();
   
    $moneyTrade->mt_number = uniqid('MTNumber-');

    $moneyTrade->bank = $request->input('bank');
    $moneyTrade->email = $request->input('email');
    $moneyTrade->mt_first_name = $request->input('mt_first_name');
    $moneyTrade->mt_last_name = $request->input('mt_last_name');
    $moneyTrade->password = $request->input('password');
    $moneyTrade->mt_account = $request->input('mt_account');
    $moneyTrade->mt_deposit = $request->input('mt_deposit');
    $moneyTrade->mt_renewFee = $request->input('mt_renewFee');
    $moneyTrade->mt_leverage = $request->input('mt_leverage');
    $moneyTrade->expiry_date = $request->input('expiry_date');

    $moneyTrade->user_id = auth()->id();
   
    $moneyTrade->save();


    //send mail
    Mail::to($moneyTrade->user->email)->send(new MoneyTradeMail($moneyTrade));

    return redirect()->route('mt.view')->withMessage('MoneyTrade Account Created');
}

    }
```

MoneyTradeController.php `update`

```
public function update(Request $request, MoneyTrade $moneyTrade)
{
    dd($request);
    $request->validate([
        'bank' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'mt_number' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255'],
        'mt_first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'mt_last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        'mt_account' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'mt_deposit' => ['required', 'integer', 'max:1000000', 'min:500'],
        'mt_renewFee' => ['required', 'integer', 'max:1000000'],
        'mt_leverage' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'expiry_date' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],


    ]);

    $moneyTrade->bank = $request->input('bank');
    $moneyTrade->mt_number = $request->input('mt_number');
    $moneyTrade->email = $request->input('email');
    $moneyTrade->mt_first_name = $request->input('mt_first_name');
    $moneyTrade->mt_last_name = $request->input('mt_last_name');
    $moneyTrade->password = $request->input('password');
    $moneyTrade->mt_account = $request->input('mt_account');
    $moneyTrade->mt_deposit = $request->input('mt_deposit');
    $moneyTrade->mt_renewFee = $request->input('mt_renewFee');
    $moneyTrade->mt_leverage = $request->input('mt_leverage');
    $moneyTrade->expiry_date = $request->input('expiry_date');

    $moneyTrade->user_id = auth()->id();

    $moneyTrade->save();

    return redirect()->route('mt.view')->withMessage('MoneyTrade Account Renewed');
}
```

And when I dump `dd($request)` I get these
[image]

Routes related in web.php

```
Route::resource('moneytrade', 'MoneyTradeController')->middleware('auth');
Route::patch('/account-renew', 'MoneyTradeController@update')->name('mt.update')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/trading-account', 'MoneyTradeController@view')->name('mt.view')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/renew', 'MoneyTradeController@renew')->name('mt.renew')->middleware('auth');
```

When I try to update nothing happens but I don't encounter any error. What am I missing on my `update` function code on in my controller? Any suggestions and help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with _"nothing happens"_? Do you not get redirect to `->route('mt.view')`?

Comment: No, the page just refreshes on the same page. When I try to dump using `dd($moneyTrade);` before saving, nothing is being passed through and the page just refreshes as well on the same one.

Comment: Could you add your routes to the question as well

Comment: I added the routes. Kindly check. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi Jemy, your second queation was,  why it create new record instead of update the current one. Because, for model binding you need to pass the parameter, change your route to `Route::patch('/account-renew/{moneyTrade}', 'MoneyTradeController@update')->name('mt.update')->middleware('auth');` hope it worked now :)

Comment: Thank you. Sorry to bother but I still get this error `Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameters for [Route: mt.update] [URI: account-renew/{moneytrade}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\fss\resources\views\moneytrade\mt-renew.blade.php)`

Comment: you are not passing the id in the url. make sure you are doing something like `{{ route('mt.update', 1//id) }}`

Comment: Sadly that didn't work. I've tried changing my route to `{{ route('mt.update', [$moneytrade->id]) }}` and the error was gone but it's still duplicating the record and not updating it instead.

Comment: Jemy, you give an extra **square bracket**, it will be `{{ route('mt.update', $moneytrade->id) }}` or `{{ route('mt.update', ['moneyTrade' => $moneytrade->id]) }}`

Comment: Thanks @sta, the route works now but it's still duplicating the record and not updating. :(

Comment: Jemy on your function change this param `MoneyTrade $moneyTrade` to `MoneyTrade $moneytrade` also change your route to `Route::patch('/account-renew/{moneytrade}', 'MoneyTradeController@update')->name('mt.update')->middleware('auth');`

Comment: @Jemy I have added an answer with the problem and solution. Check this out.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon thank you very much for your time in helping me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your validation was not passing and that's why you were being redirected. Now the second problem is route model binding. your route model binding is not working. Bind object is new and that is why it's saving a new entry in db. Your routes are

```
Route::resource('moneytrade', 'MoneyTradeController')->middleware('auth');
Route::patch('/account-renew/{moneytrade}', 'MoneyTradeController@update')->name('mt.update')->middleware('auth');
```

Look your uri moneytrade is `moneytrade` but in your controller you are binding object as `moneyTrade` where `T` is capital. In route model binding, Laravel expects the uri segment and the bind object same. Otherwise model binding won't work. If you `dd` your `$moneyTrade` object you will find it empty. So the solution here is either change the url or the controller object.
If you change route, they will be like

```
Route::resource('money-trade', 'MoneyTradeController')->middleware('auth');
or
Route::resource('moneyTrade', 'MoneyTradeController')->middleware('auth');
Route::patch('/account-renew/{moneyTrade}', 'MoneyTradeController@update')->name('mt.update')->middleware('auth');
```

And you don't have to change your controller code. If you want to change the controller but not the route then your controller would be

```
public function update(Request $request, MoneyTrade $moneytrade)
{
    dd($moneytrade);
}
```

Comment: Thank you soooooo much! You've been very helpful and it's working fine now. Now I understand further about route model binding. That's why I'm making a new instance of record rather than updating. Thanks again and I hope you stay safe! :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the confirmed rule on password is avoiding the update.

```php
$request->validate([
   ...
   'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
   ...
]);
```

There is no password_confirmed field.

Comment: That worked, thanks a lot. However it saved a new record on database instead of just updating the current ones. Should I use `$moneyTrade->update();` instead?